# Why is the two kinds of code appear different behavior in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I write this two kinds of code, the first one it appear correct render, but the second is appear incorrect empty content render, I don't know why? Is there any one can explain the behavior?

## First

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

const Header = () => {
  return <Text style={style.header}>{content}</Text>;
}

const style = {
 header: {
  fontSize: 20
 }
}

const content = "content"

export { Header };
```

## Second

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

const Header = () => {
  return <Text style={style.header}>{content}</Text>;
}

const style = {
 header: {
  fontSize: 20
 }
}

const content = () => {
  return "content"
}

export { Header };
```

Comment: I still learning JS/RN on my side and sometimes issues like this :) In the second sample, It seems you are using Fat Arrow Functions syntax So this is suppose to be bound a function to the lexical 'this' of the current context.
As you don't declare a class, I am curious to know exactly what it is doing [https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case you're defining `content` as a function. You should call it:

```
  return <Text style={style.header}>{content()}</Text>;
```